# One or more network protocols is missing on this computer

Tags: windows-10, dns, ip, tcpip

I just rebooted my Windows 10 PC, tried to connect to the internet and got a message saying "One or more network protocols is missing on this computer". The Windows troubleshooter is unable to fix the error. I have not changed the laptop at all and certainly haven't changed any protocols. How do I fix the error?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP writes in a comment on the accepted answer that the system fixed itself (an apparent hiccup), so the problem is no longer reproducible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Settings -> Network & Internet -> Ethernet (I don't use Wi-Fi so if Wi-Fi is an option, try it) -> Change adapter options -> Right-click the one you are having issues with -> Properties -> Install... -> Protocol -> Install all the protocols there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the issue seems to have sorted itself out. A restart didn't help, but something has fixed it??? :/

Comment: I have accepted anyway as it seems like the answer will fix other user's problems when they have the same issue :~)